# Generate Method Header and Implementation in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In objective-c/xcode, is there a way to write the definition of a method in the implementation and have automatically added to the header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a user script to do this.  That would probably be about the closest thing to having it done automatically...

But as noted, you don't necessarily want every method you write to go in the header, so it's better to do it selectively.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of. Often private methods are created in the implementation which you don't want to put in the header file, something which would be defeated if method signatures were automatically added to the header file.